# How will PHP Web Service read JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

My JSON is

```
{"users":[{"UserName":"user1","FullName":"Name One"},
{"UserName":"user2","FullName":"Name Two"}]}
```

My PHP is

```
<?php 
include '../inc/connect.php';
include '../inc/class/mysql.class.php'; 

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($data, true);

$rows = array();                                    
foreach ($array['users'] as $parentvalue)
    foreach ($parentvalue as $key => $value)
        $rows[] = "('" . $value . "', '" . $value . "')"; 

$values = implode(",", $rows);

try 
{
    $count = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (UserName, FullName) VALUES $values") or die(mysql_error());
}
catch(PDOException $e) { //later 
}
?>
```

The structure of the array is

```
Array
(
[users] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [FullName] => Name One
                [UserName] => user1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [FullName] => Name Two
                [UserName] => user2
            )
    )
)
```

Instead of inserting the data:
**user1 - Name One
**user2 - Name Two
to MySQL...

It inserts
**user1 - user1
**Name One - Name One
**user2 - user2
**Name Two - Name Two

Please help!

Comment: You should at least ensure that `$values` contains what it should contain, before you insert it.

Comment: Also, you're mixing using PDO with mysql_ functions, which is not going to work...

Comment: @PhilipAdler Where exactly do you see PDO here?

Comment: @djay yes thanks. i will do that after i get this working.

Comment: Post how your `$array` looks like (that comes right after `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`)

Comment: @djay there you go :)

Comment: @djay `catch(PDOException $e) { //later 
}` is where I see PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/**********EDIT (prev answer below)***********/

Here is my new code. I have modified your JSON structure based on your comments.

```
//added addresses as an example (no the postcodes aren't real :P)
$json='{
    "users":[
        {"UserName":"user1","FullName":"Name One"},
        {"UserName":"user2","FullName":"Name 2"}
    ],
    "addresses":[
        {"HouseNumber":"1","PostCode":"LS1 1PS"}, 
        {"HouseNumber": "23", "PostCode": "LS1 2PS"}  
    ]   
}';



$data=json_decode($json);

//loop over each 'table'
foreach ($data as $table_name=>$data_array){    
$table_name=mysql_real_escape_string($table_name);

//loop over each 'row' in table
foreach($data_array as $current_obj){
    $current_sql="INSERT INTO ".$table_name." SET ";
    $row=array();

    //loop through 'row' data and get 'column' name and value.
    foreach($current_obj as $name=>$value){
        $row[]='`'.mysql_real_escape_string($name).'` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($value).'"';
    }

    $current_sql.=implode(',',$row);
    mysql_query($current_sql);
    unset($current_sql,$name,$value);
    }
}
```

Now, while this code will do what you asked I probably wouldn't use it myself. I would have different endpoints in your web service for the different tables (and use GET,POST,PUT etc http requests to determine action - see REST web services) - Although its more work, clearly defined actions make debugging easier and your application more secure (as you'll know exactly what its doing and what to).

As for authentication, thats a whole issue on its own that I can't really go into here. Please don't think I mean this in an offensive way, but as you're new to development I would advise spending more time learning before trying to make anything production ready - to protect you and your customers more than anything.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Regards

Ryan

/*********** OLD ANSWER - LEFT HERE FOR CLARITY****************/

I believe you don't need the second loop. This is what I have (modify to suit your needs):

```
$json='{"users":[{"UserName":"user1","FullName":"Name One"},{"UserName":"user2","FullName":"Name 2"}]}';
$data = json_decode($json);

$rows = array();

foreach ($data->users as $user_obj){
    $rows[]='("'.$user_obj->UserName.'","'.$user_obj->FullName.'")';
}

$values = implode(",", $rows); 
echo "INSERT INTO users (UserName, FullName) VALUES ".$values;
```

Also, I would advise that you make use of prepared statements or at the very least mysql_real_escape_string.

Hope this helps,

Ryan :)

(P.s I stopped json_decode converting objects to arrays as it feel it is helpful to know when a data structure is supposed to be iterable and when it is not - feel free to change it back if you like.)

Comment: hi @Ryan! thank you! it's working. but i'm hoping for something that doest require an object name if that's possible, so that i could reuse the webservice for all my inserts on all tables.

Comment: 'mysql_real_escape_string' -- okay i will research on this one. 'prepared statements' -- i have no idea what you mean. lol. sorry i'm a newbie!

Comment: Fair enough, give me two minutes and I'll put up some more code. And don't worry about being a newbie man, we were all there once! mysql_real_escape_string or prepared statements just protect your database from SQL injection attacks by escaping data. I'll include them in my update so you can see.

Comment: thanks! but oh, but aside from that, do you think i should also authenticate the users who call the web service?

Comment: @Ryan **Please** update your answer to use prepared statements with PDO or MySQL. I know you're not actually executing the query in your example but the creation of the query and data should be done with code that uses prepared statements

Comment: @Ryan thanks for your help and advice. Noted - everything. I will weigh my options and do more research and use your code as a guide. thanks again!

Comment: Sorry @Raii I misread your comments on authentication. Yeah I would definitely verify that the users of your web service are actually allowed to use it. You really should verify that the data provided is the data you're expecting too, and limit the number of inserts etc. Either way, In their current form the scripts I've given are pretty open to abuse and you should definitely implement some measures to prevent this.

Just seen your new reply: No problem, I hope it helps and you know where I am if you have any more questions :)

Comment: aaaah! too many things to research on and consider. so i guess i have to start goggling right away lol. alright thanks Ryan! ^^

Answer (score 1):

I slightly improved your code, for readability's sake. The very first thing you'd realize is that you're dealing with **two** problems here : one is parsing JSON response, and the second one is inserting records into a table:

```
$json = '{"users":[{"UserName":"user1","FullName":"Name One"},
{"UserName":"user2","FullName":"Name Two"}]}';

$values = buildArray($json);
insertValues($values);


function buildArray($json) {

    $result = array();
    $array = array_values(json_decode($json, true));

    foreach ($array as $index => $nestedArray) {
        foreach($nestedArray as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}



function insertValues(array $values) {

    foreach($values as $index => $array) {

        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`UserName`, `FullName`) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", 
            mysql_real_escape_string($array['UserName']), 
            mysql_real_escape_string($array['FullName']), 
        );

        if (!mysql_unbuffered_query($query)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks @djay! but i'm hoping for something that doesnt require an object name if that's possible, so that i could reuse the webservice for all my inserts on all tables.

Comment: but i'm not sure. do you think using objects is like the best practice? or maybe using an array is more efficient?

Comment: are you suggesting that i create one function for each table insert? or just pass tablenames as variables and just use that 'insertValues' function?

Comment: You would create one function that insert values and that requires a table name and array of key => value pairs that need to be inserted.

Comment: i would probably go with one function for each insert. cause i realize there would be a lot of wheres and conditions for each query. thanks a lot for your help, especially on teaching me this one -> mysql_unbuffered_query.